# Scene unpauses with transitioning to other scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have scene which successfully paused with:

```
self.scene.isPaused = true
```

But when it is paused I make transition to other scene:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = touches.first!.location(in: self)
        let node = self.atPoint(location)

        if node.name == "pause" {
            self.scene?.isPaused = true
            sceneManager.gameScene = self
            let transition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 1.0)
            let pauseScene = PauseScene(size: self.size)
            pauseScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.scene!.view?.presentScene(pauseScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
```

If i comment out code below **self.scene?.isPaused = true** my scene really paused and no sprites moving or spawning. This paused scene I save into **scene manager** singleton:

```
class SceneManager {
    static let shared = SceneManager()

    var gameScene: GameScene?
}
```

When I come back I check for the scene in my scene manager if it is scene I use it. But anyway when I come back to paused scene I see that it is not paused at all and all sprites are moving. But the only difference that there are no collisions detected while I'am on other screen.

So how can I make it REALLY paused when I'am on the other screen?

Thank you!

**EDITED:**
I found out that paused scene (game scene) unpausing in update method of pause scene. So I wrote in update method next:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if let gameScene = sceneManager.gameScene {
        if !gameScene.isPaused {
            sceneManager.gameScene?.isPaused = true
            print("CHANGED")
        }
    }
}
```

Interesting that **sceneManager.gameScene?.isPaused** in **didMove(_toView)** still **true**, but when I move to update method it becomes **false** and that is the reason I wrote such code in update method.
Now everything working correctly.

But if this is a good practice to put such code in update method?

Comment: I would override your scene isPaused property, not do it on update

Comment: I think I mentioned this before, you need to stop it from changing the value of the children, so do not call `super.isPaused =` when overriding

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I never call super.isPaused. But for now I left it in update. There no places where I call scene.isPaused = false.

Comment: ... no you override isPaused and make sure you do not call super.isPaused when overriding.  Just because you do not call it does not mean the system never calls it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you answer it how can I do it? If it will help me I could accept it as a correct answer because I don't really like my snippet.

Comment: if you know how to override update, you know how to override isPaused, just swap func for var

Comment: yes I know I don't understand why it should help and why now it is not working

Comment: already explained it in a different question you asked,  go see that.